# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 388: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas

I am really beginning at python, but I am hours in this line, can't go anywhere without fixing it.

```
cadastro_2019_10= pd.read_csv("inf_cadastral_fi_20191015.csv",delimiter=";")[["CNPJ_FUNDO","DENOM_SOCIAL","CLASSE"]]
```

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 49: invalid continuation byte

```
cadastro_2019_10= pd.read_csv("inf_cadastral_fi_20191015.csv",delimiter=";")[["CNPJ_FUNDO","DENOM_SOCIAL","CLASSE"]]
```

again:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 388: invalid continuation byte

Answer (score 1):

Figure out what encoding the CSV file uses. Seems it doesn't use UTF-8. Say it's latin1, then you can try with `read_csv(..., encoding="latin1")`.

If you are on a UNIX system, you can use the `file` command to try to detect the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to add :encoding='cp1252'
but thank you for your time